# Muse site to sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-designer, muse

I am new to SharePoint and I have an Adobe MUSE site and I would like to apply to my MS SharePoint site as a subsite. I could not find anything via google search on how to go about in accomplishing this. How would I go about applying my muse site into my SharePoint?

Answer (score 1):

I used SharePoint Designer, opened up my subsite and loaded all of the published HTML files from Muse to **Site Pages**. Once there, I set MY **index.html** file  to be the HOME page (right-click 'Set as Home Page') for that site (URL). Now, when I go to the site address (eshare.[domain].com/[yoursite]/[yoursubsite]) it shows all of my custom Muse content and nothing from the SharePoint platform.

[Site Pages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QWUzs.gif)